# Syntax Error Unexpected token DOCTYPE is not valid JSON Next js code

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, next.js, rxjs

**I was building a nextjs app that register a retailers and display list of retailers in my fetch-wrapper handleResponse function is not working properly code snippet**

I have a db,json file i tried it with empty json and with data it doesn't work in both way

```js
export const fetchWrapper = {
    get,
    post,
    put,
    delete: _delete
};

async function get(url) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET'
    };
    const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
    return handleResponse(response);
}

async function post(url, body) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    };
    const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
    return handleResponse(response);
}

async function put(url, body) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    };
    const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
    return handleResponse(response);
}

// prefixed with underscored because delete is a reserved word in javascript
async function _delete(url) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'DELETE'
    };
    const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
    return handleResponse(response);
}

// helper functions

function handleResponse(response) {
    return response.text().then(text => {
        const data = text && JSON.parse(text);

        if (!response.ok) {
            const error = (data && data.message) || response.statusText;
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        return data;
    });
}
```

Comment: You're JSON-parsing `text` without first checking if the response was okay.

Comment: If you log `text` to the console (in `handleResponse`), what's the output?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm struggling to solve a similar problem